# Javascript OO / jQuery.class() plug in causing problems

Tags: jquery, oop, meteor

I'm working with some code that uses a jQuery plugin to give class style inheritance(http://v3.javascriptmvc.com/docs/jQuery.Class.html#&who=jQuery.Class). It's causing me a lot of problems. In particular, the class is evaluated before it is called. So when I try to do:

```
$.Class.extend('Mountain',{
    //@static
        init: function() { 
            this.elev = new google.maps.ElevationService();
        }
        });
```

I can't because this code is run before Google maps loads, leading to an undefined error. I was hoping to attach a listener to Google maps load event and then call Mountain.inti(), while I can do this the original class runs before I've the load event, still causing the error.

Any advice? Perhaps my diagnosis is wrong? This is all running in meteor, though I'm not sure if that's relevant...

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [MapsEventListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener)